# Php session_destroy() is destroying all sessions in a browser

Tags: php, session

I have two admin panels with different files and folders and when i destroying session after logging out from one admin panel  it automatically destroying the other admin panel session, they both have different session names and variables .

`session_unset($_SESSION['ticket_level']);
        session_unset($_SESSION['ticket_name']);
                session_destroy();
        header("location: ../login.php");`

this is something i am using for one of them , i am not sure what the heck is going on or is this the right way to do it for not

Comment: Maybe set them to false and try to check that way?

Comment: session_unset/session_register/etc... are deprecated and should NOT be used.

Answer (score 1):

Use [session_name()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) for different applications running on the same server. Ex:

Site A:

```
session_name('site_A');
```

Site B

```
session_name('site_B');
```

You must call it before `session_start()` and on every single page.

Comment: Good solution I never even knew of. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
unset($_SESSION['ticket_level']);
```

session_unset is obsolet and is not meant to be used like this (it takes void as params)